# Standard deviation of one element

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

When I try to execute

```
StandardDeviation[{1}]
```

I get an error

```
StandardDeviation::shlen: "The argument {1} should have at least two elements"
```

But std of one element is 0, isn't it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The standard deviation is commonly defined as the square-root of the *unbiased* estimator of the variance:

[image]

You can easily see that for a single sample, `N=1` and you get `0/0`, which is undefined. Hence your standard deviation is undefined for a single sample in Mathematica.

Now depending on your conventions, you might want to define a standard deviation for a single sample (either return `Null` or some value or `0`). Here's an example that shows you how to define it for a single sample.

```
std[x_List] := Which[(Length[x] == 1), 0, True, StandardDeviation[x]]
std[{1}]
Out[1]= 0
```

Comment: The standard deviation of a population of size 1 is 0 (use $\sigma$ and division by $N$ in the formula), while the standard deviation of a sample of size 1 is infinite (use $s$ and division by $N-1$ in the formula).

Answer (score 8):

The standard deviation of a constant is zero.

The estimated standard deviation of one sample is undefined.

Comment: I agree with you but suggest you make your reasoning more explicit by showing the formulas for a s.d of a population and a s.d. of a sample. Your comment to moodywoody is a great start.

Comment: This is true for the stddev of a sample (`1/(N-1)`), but for the stddev of a population there is a `1 / N` so the stddev would be zero. This was mentioned in the comment in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want some formality:

```
p[x_] := DiracDelta[x - mu];
expValue = Integrate[x p[x] , {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
stdDev = Sqrt[Integrate[(x - expValue)^2 p[x] , {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]]

(*
-> ConditionalExpression[mu, mu \[Element] Reals]
-> ConditionalExpression[0, mu \[Element] Reals]
*)
```

**Edit**

Or better, using Mathematica `ProbabilityDistribution[]`:

```
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[DiracDelta[x - mu], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}];
{Mean[dist], StandardDeviation[dist]}

(*
 -> { mu, ConditionalExpression[0, mu \[Element] Reals]}
*)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your population size is one element, then yes the standard deviation of your population will be 0. However typically standard deviations are used on samples, and not on the entire population, so instead of dividing by the number of elements in the sample, you divide by the number of elements minus one. This is due to the error inherent in performing calculations on a sample, rather than a population.

Performing a calculation of the standard deviation over a population of size 1 makes absolutely no sense, which I think is where the confusion is coming from. If you know that your population contains only one element then finding out the standard deviation of that element is pointless, so generally you will see the standard deviation of a single element written as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Standard deviation - which is a measure for the deviation of the actual value from the average of a given set - for a list of one element doesn't make any sense (you can set it to 0 if you want).

Comment: I don't understand that. The average for a set of one element equals to that element, so deviation is 0. It's a degenerate case, but still there's a value for that case.

Comment: No, you get `sqrt( (1 - 1) * (1 - 1) / ( 1 - 1) )` = `sqrt( 0 / 0 )` = `undefined`. If you do not know the mean, you have to divide by `n - 1`.

Comment: According to the doco Mathematica calculates StdDev as sqrt(var) which is defined in ( http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Variance.html ) .. note the divided by (Length[list]-1)  part ... so I guess it's an implementation choice

Comment: @moodywoody It's not an implementation choice. Dividing by n-1 is commonly done to calculate the unbiased standard deviation of a sample. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation